# Use NextApiResponse helper in NextJs 13.2 Route Handlers (app/route)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, next.js

Before in the `pages/api` method the handler looked like `handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse)`. In NextJs 13.2 they introduced Route Handlers in the `app/api/route` and the handler for a POST request looks like `POST(req: NextRequest): NextResponse`.

Well I ran into this limitation when revalidating for on-demand ISR.
This is what I have:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    // (...)
    await res.revalidate('/projects');
    res.status(200).json({ revalidated: true });
}
```

I was trying to refactor to the Nextjs 13.2 way and find a way to use the NextApiResponse helper but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: For on-demand revalidation, for now, you can only use the `pages` folder for your route handler. As you can read on the [doc](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating#using-on-demand-revalidation)